# Find element that has no direct children with specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tree-traversal

In a page of HTML elements, I am trying to find a parent element with class `.dmc` that does not contain a direct child element with a specific class `.dynamic`, using JQuery.

I have tried:

```
$('.dmc:not(:has(.dynamic))')
```

However this checks all descendants, and I only want to check the first level of descendants.

I think there is a very simple answer, but I can't quite come up with it. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `:has` is already jQuery-specific, you could use an unrooted `>`, which jQuery's Sizzle selector engine seems to support:

```
$(".dmc:not(:has(> .dynamic))").addClass("green");
// --------------^
```

```js
$(".dmc:not(:has(> .dynamic))").addClass("green");
```

```css
.green {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="dmc">1</div>
<div class="dmc">2
  <div class="dynamic">dynamic</div>
</div>
<div class="dmc">3</div>
<div class="dmc">4
  <div class="dynamic">dynamic</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**But** I'd be slightly worried about it, and would probably go for `filter` instead:

```
$(".dmc").filter(function() {
  return $(this).children(".dynamic").length == 0;
}).addClass("green");
```

```js
$(".dmc").filter(function() {
  return $(this).children(".dynamic").length == 0;
}).addClass("green");
```

```css
.green {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="dmc">1</div>
<div class="dmc">2
  <div class="dynamic">dynamic</div>
</div>
<div class="dmc">3</div>
<div class="dmc">4
  <div class="dynamic">dynamic</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```